# How to read and write to mounted volume without running as root?

Tags: docker

When mounting a volume with the following command:

```
docker run -t -i --volumes-from FOO BAR
```

the volumes from FOO are mounted with root as owner. I can't read and write to that without running as root as far as I know. Must I run as root or is there some other way?

I have tried by creating the folder with other owner before mounting but the mounting seems to overwrite that.

---

Edit: A `chown` would work if it could be done automatically after the mounting somehow.

Comment: Can you change the ownership of the files in your source container?

Comment: There's nothing special about docker here.  If you want to write to a directory as an unprivileged user, you need to make use of `chown`, `chgrp`, and `chmod` to set the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Yea I realize that a `chown` works. I actually tried that with `docker exec -it ### bash` and it works fine. But I don't want to have to do that every time. The file is a database file generated at runtime of the Dockerfile so no I don't see how to change it nor what to change it to. I think I need a `chown` to be called as root after the `--volumes-from` thing has kicked in but how to do that?

Comment: Why does the chown need to run after the mount? Why not as part of your image creation or on the source image run?

Comment: I have tried it from the Dockerfile but it seem as the volume is mounted (way later) any owners of that path is reset to root.

Comment: Sadly, this seems confirmed by: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you aren't able to change your folder permissions in your source image. This works without issue in my lab:

```
$ cat df.vf-uid
FROM busybox

RUN mkdir -p /data && echo "hello world" > /data/hello && chown -R 1000 /data

$ docker build -f df.vf-uid -t test-vf-uid .
...
Successfully built 41390b132940

$ docker create --name test-vf-uid -v /data test-vf-uid
e12df8f84a3b1f113ad5440b62552b40c4fd86f99eec44698af9163a7b960727

$ docker run --volumes-from test-vf-uid -u 1000 -it --rm busybox /bin/sh
/ $ ls -al /data
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    2 1000     root          4096 Aug 22 11:44 .
drwxr-xr-x   19 root     root          4096 Aug 22 11:45 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     root            12 Aug 22 11:43 hello
/ $ echo "success" >/data/world
/ $ ls -al /data
total 16
drwxr-xr-x    2 1000     root          4096 Aug 22 11:46 .
drwxr-xr-x   19 root     root          4096 Aug 22 11:45 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     root            12 Aug 22 11:43 hello
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     root             8 Aug 22 11:46 world
/ $ cat /data/hello /data/world
hello world
success
/ $ exit
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are doing, it seems sort of similar to my solution, but if you say that it works I guess it does. :)

Comment: The dockerfile is two lines, with the RUN that changes the UID of the /data folder. I build and create the container (not necessary to run it). Then I run an interactive container as UID 1000 with the `--volumes-from` option and see that /data is listed with UID 1000.

Comment: This was trying to reproduce [your comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020093/how-to-read-and-write-to-mounted-volume-without-running-as-root/39078791?noredirect=1#comment65395179_39020093). From my testing, Docker did not reset the directory permissions to root in my image when I mounted it.

Comment: Ah OK. Yea you are right. I tried to change inside the container before mounting. But the mount of course doesn't care about what it overshadows

Comment: Oh, yes, changing the target container with different permissions and then mounting over that won't work at all. That would explain the difference in behavior you saw. It needs to be done in the source container. If your source image is managed upstream, you can always do a `FROM source:latest ... RUN chown -R 1000 /path` to make a new source container with different permissions.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I ended up doing was mounting the volume to another container and change the owner (using uid of the owner I wanted in the final setup) from that container. Apparently uid's are uid's regardless. This means that I can run without being root in the final container. Perhaps there are easier ways to do it but this seems to work at least. Something like this: (untested code clip from my final solution)

```
docker run -v /opt/app --name Foo ubuntu /bin/bash
docker run --rm --volumes-from Foo -v $(pwd):/FOO ubuntu bash -c "chown -R 9999 /opt/app"
docker run -t -i --volumes-from FOO BAR
```